# How to get visual email and message notifications on lockscreen?

Tags: notifications, lock-screens

I am very new to Android. I tried searching in this forum and google in general without finding an answer.

I would like to be able to see notifications on my unlock screen. For example, 3 unread gmail messages, 5 unread exchange messages, 1 new sms, 2 new voicemail. Is this possible?

If this is not possible can I at least do it on my home screen? I have widgets for all these there, but they don't seem to show a little number on the icon with unread.

I feel as though this is a no-brainer feature, but I just can' figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

[GOTO Lockscreen](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.innowebtech.g0t0&hl=en) is probably what you want! It gives you information about your incoming notifications, allows you to navigate straight to them from the unlock screen, and is fully customizeable.

If you don't find that helpful, [WidgetLocker](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker&feature=related_apps) could probably help you out too :)

**BONUS:** If you add [ADW Notifier](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.adw.launcher.notifications&hl=en) with either of these, you will get small number icons to alert you to any unattented-to actions graphically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the notifications immediately, you can get them even when the display is "off" with [NoLED](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.led.notify) (if your device is compatible). Note that this was designed for AMOLED displays, so it might eat a lot of battery on other screens.